# Calling a method via another method

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, methods, view

I know I'm missing something basic. How do I invoke the `checkValue` method from inside the `startup` method (the commented line)?  This is all contained within the view in an MVC framework and a custom API.

Essentially, when `startup` runs, I want the `alert()` to fire.

```
define(function(require) {
  'use strict';
  var Class = require('common/Class'),
      ModuleView = require('common/platform/ModuleView');

  var value = 0;

  return Class.create(
    ModuleView,
    {

      startup : function() {
        value = 1;
        //invoke checkValue(value) somehow... this.checkValue(value)?
      },

      checkValue: function(value) {
        if (value >= 1) {
          alert("Hello.");
        }
      }

    }
  );

});
```

Comment: haha, yeah never know 'til you try. Debug into it, check out "this" inside "startup" to see if it's the window or if it's an object that has a "checkValue" function or if it's some other thing that can get you to your object with that function.

Comment: @JohnnyFun Great idea, but genuine question: How would I go about debugging ``this`` and seeing what its scope is?

Comment: Looks like that answer below is probably your ticket out of this. BUT, it's good to know js debugging techniques to get yourself out of hairy situations, so familiarize yourself with Chrome's dev tools. Assuming you're viewing your page in chrome, hit F12. Then hit ctrl + p and find your script. Once there, you can place a breakpoint inside your "startup" function by clicking the line numbers to the right. Then reload the page and chrome will hit that breakpoint for you. While you're on the breakpoint, you can click the console tab and write "this" + hit enter to see what secrets it harbors...

Comment: @JohnnyFun Thanks, that was extremely educational!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about writing the class like this:

```
return Class.create(ModelView, modelView());

function modelView() {
    this.startup = function() {
        value = 1;
        this.checkValue(value);
    }
    this.checkValue = function(value) {
        if (value >= 1)
            alert("Hello.");
    }
}
```

This way you can also use this class multiple times by declaring a new instance.

Comment: I'll give it a go and report back. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: You might also want to declare value inside the class... I'm not sure why you've declared it outside the class.

Comment: It works. It will require a ton of rewriting, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Well, never mind. It works in a pure JS sense, but their API completely breaks it. Not sure why yet. Regardless, I'll keep fiddling with it.

Comment: Happy to help. Is this a private API btw?

Comment: Yes, partially private.